# Monodroid java library binding: How to set all constructors public

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, java

I'm trying to bing java library to my monodroid project. I'm using Amazon Mobile Associates library, and I'm trying to do this:

> AssociatesAPI.Initialize(new AssociatesAPI.Config(APPLICATION_KEY, this));

Unfortunatelly, even if this AssociatesAPI.Config(string, context) constructor is public, it's using the second  constructor :

```
public Config (string p0, Context p1) : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
```

and the constructor

```
protected Config (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base (javaReference, transfer)
```

is protected.

When I use **Metadata.xml** I can set class constructor public:

```
< attr path="/api/package[@name='com.amazon.device.associates']/class[@name='AssociatesAPI.Config']/constructor" name="visibility">public< /attr>
```

but this sets just this one constructor and the protected one stays protected. So when I use this library in my app I get **errors**:

```
Error CS1540: Cannot access protected member   `Com.Amazon.Device.Associates.AssociatesAPI.Config.Config(System.IntPtr,     Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)' via a qualifier of type     `Com.Amazon.Device.Associates.AssociatesAPI.Config'. 

The qualifier must be of type `Mews.Client.Navigator.TabletAndroid.Activities.Services.ServiceDetailActivity' (<i>this is my activity I'm passing as a Context</i>) or derived from it (CS1540)
```

and

```
Error CS0122: `Com.Amazon.Device.Associates.AssociatesAPI.Config.Config(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122) (Mews.Client.Navigator.TabletAndroid)
```

Also when i compile library project, there's no error or warning about not found node or wrong xpath, that usually appears when specifying wrong path or class name in attr.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this in Transforms/Metadata.xml :

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='Name_of_the_package']/class[@name='myclass']/method[@name='methodname']" name="visibility"> public</attr>
```